# Wordpress Custom Meta Query Search is so slow when in OR relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I made a search which is basically querying custom meta fields and showing the results. For some reason, the search takes endless hours. When I change the relation to "**AND**" it works great but when I change the relation to "**OR**" it's dead.

Currently in the database I have 5 records so it shouldn't take time.

**This is the query**

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'shipping-schedules', 
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => 'schedules_port',
      'value' => $sfrom,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'schedules_port',
      'value' => $sto,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'schedules_vessel',
      'value' => $svessel,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'schedules_voyage',
      'value' => $svoyage,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'schedules_arrival',
      'value' => $sdate_arrival,
      'compare' => '>=',
      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'schedules_departure',
      'value' => $sdate_departure,
      'compare' => '<=',
      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    )
  )
);
```

As you can see in the above query this line `'relation' => 'AND'` changing it to `'relation' => 'OR'` will result the problem am facing slow querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this problem too... but the problem is I needed to use OR for my particular case.

After reading a ton of info, such as indexing the post meta table values (this actually sounds like a good idea, but my code was in a plugin so couldn't do this) I found a way that seems to run the same query a lot faster.

I have no idea why, and haven't begun to poke around under the hood, but instead of doing a WP meta query use the filter `posts_where` and modify the WHERE clause yourself adding in your own arguments..

Here's my code:

```
add_filter('posts_where', array($this, 'filter_meta_query_where')); //modify the where clause to filter meta data
add_filter('posts_join' , array($this, 'filter_meta_join')); //join the meta table to the posts query
```

This is the main function that adds the meta query (I've added conditions for `schedules_port`, you'll have to build the rest yourself the way you want):

```
function filter_meta_query_where($where = '')
{
    global $wpdb; 
    global $wp_query;
    global $sf_form_data;

    if(!is_admin())
    {
        $where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'schedules_port' AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$sfrom%' OR $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$sto%')))";
    }

    return $where;
}
```

And here's the code for the join

```
function filter_meta_join($join)
{
     global $wpdb;

     $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id ";

     return $join;
}
```

Hope that helps